# Restore values in fragment on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my Fragment.class.....I'm getting the totalprice perfectly but once the fragment is back pressed and created again the totalprice is always showing 0...That is the totalprice value is recreated....please help me to store the value everytime its newly created....

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
activity = getActivity();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_product_list, container,false);
subTotal = (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_total);
totalPrice = totalPrice.add(price);
subTotal.setText("Total: " + totalPrice + " $");
return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SharedPreferences to preserve value like below
Save totalPrice as below in onPause of fragment

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("totalPrice", totalPrice);
editor.commit();
```

Read back in onCreate when it comes back

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
totalPrice = sharedPref.getInt(totalPrice, defaultValue);
```

Comment: what is the defaultvalue here?

Comment: It is the value to return if there is no preference in your case it will be 0

Comment: Show the updated code with sharedpreference implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code in onStart so that it's reloaded when back is pressed.
(That is, assuming you have the value of totalprice, and want to load it correctly when back is pressed, try this code ..)

```
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        subTotal = (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_total);
        totalPrice = totalPrice.add(price);
        subTotal.setText("Total: " + totalPrice + " $");
 }
```